# Can we use laravel blade templates in vue routing instead of vue components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

Is it possible to use laravel blade templates instead of vue components to route using vue routing? I want to route my blade files without page refreshing as we do in Spa using vue routing.

```
import App from './views/App'
import Hello from './views/Hello'
import Home from './views/Home'
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home', 
            component: Home //Vue Component
        },
        {
            path: '/hello',
            name: 'hello',
            component: Hello, //Vue Component
        },
    ],
});
```

I want to use blade files instead of vue components that I have made named as home and hello

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't. Since Laravel is not actually serving `*.blade.php` files to you but rather compiles them to plain PHP, puts into `storage/framework/views` *(by default)* folder and then serves.

From [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#introduction):

> In fact, all Blade views are compiled into plain PHP code and cached until they are modified

So in any case, there would have to happen a *page refresh* to serve other PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to get html as response and render in vue.

In your controller:

```php
public function renderHtml()
{
   $data = ... ;
   $html = view('test',compact('data')->render();
   return response()->json($html);
}
```

In your Vue component use vanilla JS or jquery to get the markup and bind it to the comonent

```js
fetch('renderhtml')
   .then(response => () {
       element.innerHTML(response.data);
});
```

Note that this is not a really reliable solution for every case.

Comment: Noual Fouzi Sir! but then i have to render every blade file into json response and then fetch it which is also a lengthy process.

Comment: i just want to know that is it possible to use blade files instead of vue component to to route using vue routing? Currently i need to made component for every blade file so that i can apply vue routing but this is not useful for big applications.