# Implementing SPA on Laravel blade php with Vue js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm having a trouble on how to implement `Single Page Application` on Laravel blade `php file format` using `Vue-router`, is that possible?.The reference link below says that it is impossible to use SPA on php file format and I'm here to ask to confirm if this is not possible, but I guess there is other solution with this issue. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56755258/can-we-use-laravel-blade-templates-in-vue-routing-instead-of-vue-components/56757185#56757185)

For example with this file it should blade.php instead of vue

[image]

Comment: can you tell us which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: @Sanmit Pawar thanks for your response , I'm been using Laravel version 7.30.3. Is there any solution in the latest version?

Comment: please check the link for same : https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2018/02/05/vue-laravel-crud/

Comment: You use a single entry point and not multiple blades.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Actually I'm been using singleton coding pattern and the requirements from my project manager we should using blade.php file, based on the comment below the laravel have some standards.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Actually I'm been using singleton coding pattern and the requirements from my project manager we should using blade.php file, based on the comment below the laravel have some standards.

Comment: @jeremykenedy Actually I'm been using singleton coding pattern and the requirements from my project manager we should using blade.php file, based on the comment below the laravel have some standards.

Comment: enter the single blade and then use vue router if you want a SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible ..laravel have some standards that need to follow

Blade view files use the .blade.php file extension and are typically stored in the resources/views directory.

SPA are fast since most resources (HTML,CSSS,Scripts etc) and DOM components are only loaded once throughout the entire cycle of an application. Subsequently, only dynamic content is loaded by JS, which speeds up the site remarkably.
If you are using blade then it needs to reload for every changes to reflect then what points of using it

Refer this: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would opt for L8 with inertiajs(vuejs) which is integrated in the documentation and you can easily make a SPA

Comment: Thanks for your response , I want the blade.php format to be my SPA pages not the vue component, I've already check the example of inertiajs like this example [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwqnh.png) all I want those file should `blade.php` and implemented by SPA it is possible?

Comment: how do you want to make a SPA without javascript? in pure PHP it is impossible to do SPA, go with inertiajs it's very easy.